# CorePlot CPTXYGraph Y-Axis Integer not decimal

Tags: core-plot

In CorePlot CPTXYGraph is it possible to display int values on the Y axis instead of decimal values?

Comment: Solved:


NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterNoStyle];
    [numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
    [numberFormatter setPositiveFormat:@"###0"];

Answer (score 6):

just create a number formatter and apply it to the y axis. something like this

```
    NSNumberFormatter *yLabelFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [yLabelFormatter setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:NO];

    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
    CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;

    y.labelFormatter = yLabelFormatter
```